# show hidden span with display:block not working on hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a `span` on an `image` which I hide using `display:none`. Trying to show it with `display:block` on hover is not working. Can any one help me?

```css
.imagegood {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  display: none;
}
.ShowHidden:hover {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; text-align:center;margin-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center ">
  <a class="ShowHidden" href="#">
    <div>
      <img style="width:100% ; height:auto;" class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg" />
      <span class="imagegood">GoodTitle</span>
    </div>


  </a>
  <h3 style="font-weight:bold;" class="h">GoodTitle</h3>
  <h5 class="h">GoodSubText</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following

```
.ShowHidden:hover .imagegood{
    display:block;
}
```

```css
.imagegood{
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
background-color:white;
color:black;
padding:10px;
font-size:large;
transition: 1s all;
opacity: 0;
}
.ShowHidden:hover .imagegood{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div  style="position:relative; text-align:center;margin-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center ">
        <a class="ShowHidden" href="#">
            <div>
                <img style="width:100% ; height:auto;" class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg" />
                <span class="imagegood">GoodTitle</span>
            </div>


        </a>
            <h3 style="font-weight:bold;" class="h">GoodTitle</h3>
        <h5 class="h">GoodSubText</h5>
```

Comment: thank you dear , I'm new in programming . your codes works fine thanks . I want some transition when it appears . it is possible ?

Comment: What type of effect you want @shimaamini?

Comment: span appeared a little slowly . it is possible with css ?

Comment: See updated code @shimaamini i have added animation. Here i am using `opacity` in this.

Answer (score 1):

Used to this

```
.ShowHidden:hover .imagegood{
    display:inline-block ;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmrkzs7t/2/)**

Code

```css
.imagegood{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:large;
    display:none;
}
.ShowHidden:hover  .imagegood{
    display:inline-block ;
}
```

```html
<div  style="position:relative; text-align:center;margin-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center ">
            <a class="ShowHidden" href="#">
                <div>
                    <img style="width:100% ; height:auto;" class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg" />
                    <span class="imagegood">GoodTitle</span>
                </div>
                

            </a>
                <h3 style="font-weight:bold;" class="h">GoodTitle</h3>
            <h5 class="h">GoodSubText</h5>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think you should try is `visibility: hidden;` vs `display: none;`

`display: none;` removes it from the page - you can still interact with it in the dev tools, but can't see it where as `visibility: hidden` has allocated dom space.

see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already given but for your understanding :

If you want to hide and show any element then target that element too like you hide the span so on hove use span also like this `.ShowHidden:hover span`

If you are hiding div then use div instead of span or you can use class/id name also.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmrkzs7t/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JQuery

```
$(".imagegood")..mouseover(function() {
 $( ".center-block").fadeIn();
});
```

you can even have it popup for 3sec

```
 $( ".center-block").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

take a look at this link http://api.jquery.com/fadein/